# Ethereum transaction giving error 'invalid sender'

Tags: web3js, transactions, ethereumjs

This is how my contract looks like -

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.8.0;


contract Calculator {
    uint public result;

    event Added(address caller, uint a, uint b, uint res);

    constructor() public {
        result = 777;
    }

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns (uint, address) {
        result = a + b;
        emit Added(msg.sender, a, b, result);
        return (result, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Above contract is deployed on Ropsten test net. And I am trying to invoke the `add(...)` function with a transaction. And my code looks like this -

```
const accountAddress = rtUtil.getAccountAddress();
const accountPk = Buffer.from(rtUtil.getAccountAddressPk(), "hex");
const contract = await rtUtil.getCalculatorContract();
const data = contract.methods.add(3, 74).encodeABI();

const web3 = rtUtil.getWeb3();
const taxCount = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress);

const txObject = {
   nonce: web3.utils.toHex(taxCount),
   to: rtUtil.getCalculatorContractAddress(),
   value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0', 'ether')),
   gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100000),
   gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('6', 'gwei')),
   data: data
};

const commmon = new Common({chain: "ropsten", hardfork: "petersburg"});
const tx = Transaction.fromTxData(txObject, {commmon});
tx.sign(accountPk);

const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
const raw = web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx);
const transaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw);
```

And when I run the code I get error -

```
Uncaught Error: Returned error: invalid sender
Process exited with code 1
```

My Nodejs versions is `v15.1.0`

And my `package.json` dependencies are -

```
"dependencies": {
  "@ethereumjs/common": "^2.0.0",
  "@ethereumjs/tx": "^3.0.0",
  "@truffle/contract": "^4.2.30",
  "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.2.0",
  "web3": "^1.3.0"
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem likely comes from these two lines :

```
tx.sign(accountPk);
const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
```

This was correct in the v2 of ethereumjs-tx but this is not anymore in the v3 release.

What you are doing here is serializing the **unsigned** transaction. Indeed we can read in the comments at the top of the `sign` method (see https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/blob/6c0490056cdd1b5c45f6b74f21a0e317e1e5f082/packages/tx/src/transaction.ts#L227) :

> Sign a transaction with a given private key.
> **Returns a new Transaction object (the original tx will not be modified).**

You need to save the signed transaction in a variable and apply serialization to it :

```
const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey)
const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize()
```

**Note** : There is an archive folder for the v2 (https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx), not to be confused with the folder dedicated to the v3 and current releases : https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-vm/tree/master/packages/tx.

Comment: I have changed my code according to your suggestion, but still getting same error -

`const signedTx = tx.sign(accountPkBuffer);`
`const serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();`
`const raw = await web3.utils.toHex(serializedTx);`
`const transaction = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw);`